# EJB 3.1 lookup returns null remote object

Tags: ejb-3.1

I am using *EJB3* deployed on *WAS 8*.
I am accessing this EJB from my *WEB server* using *Context.lookup*.
This look up works fine and the entire application works fine for the first time after *WAS* is restarted.
However when I run the application for the second time, the look up does happen, but a NULL value is returned.
I dont get any exception or error or any logs on *WAS*.

Again if I restart the *WAS*, the application works well.

Can anyone please guide what the issue can be?

Answer (score 0):

Remote references are connection-less proxies. If the application is redeployed/undeployed or there is network failure, the proxies are invalidated.

You can use ServiceLocator pattern for caching the references of the remote objects. You can remove & again re-create them with JNDI lookup when they become invalid.